# MongoDB retrieval error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I am retrieving a document from MongoDB using find() in Node.js, while printing the result I am not getting the retrieved values. Here my code..

```
       db.collection("Product").find({'entry_id':entryID},function(err, result) {
        console.log("Output:",result);
```

Comment: What are the retrieved values? Are you sure your query is correct? If mongodb finds no matching documents it wont give you an error, it will just give you a `null` result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just about place money on `entry_id` is an `ObjectId` value and what you are passing as a variable is actually just a string.

But the other obvious thing is that you are using `.find()` in the wrong way. The "result" returned is a 
"cursor". If you want something that looks like a whole result set, then use [`.toArray()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/1.4/api-generated/cursor.html#toarray) or other similar method of conversion:

```
       var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

       db.collection("Product").find({
           'entry_id': new ObjectID(entryID)
       }).toArray(function(err, result) {
        console.log("Output:",result);
       });
```